# Fastest way to find indices of condition in numpy array

Tags: python, performance, numpy, cython

I'm trying to find the fastest way to to get the functionality of numpy's 'where' statement on a 2D numpy array; namely, retrieving the indices where a condition is met. It is simply much slower than other languages I have used (e.g., IDL, Matlab).

I have [cythonized](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/cython_tutorial.html) a function that marches through the array in nested for-loops. There is almost an order of magnitude increase in speed, but I would like to increase performance even more, if possible.

TEST.py:

```
from cython_where import *
import time
import numpy as np

data = np.zeros((2600,5200))
data[100:200,100:200] = 10

t0 = time.time()
inds,ct = cython_where(data,'EQ',10)
print time.time() - t0

t1 = time.time()
tmp = np.where(data == 10)
print time.time() - t1
```

My cython_where.pyx program:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython

DTYPE1 = np.float
ctypedef np.float_t DTYPE1_t
DTYPE2 = np.int
ctypedef np.int_t DTYPE2_t

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.nonecheck(False)

def cython_where(np.ndarray[DTYPE1_t, ndim=2] data, oper, DTYPE1_t val):
  assert data.dtype == DTYPE1

  cdef int xmax = data.shape[0]
  cdef int ymax = data.shape[1]
  cdef unsigned int x, y
  cdef int count = 0
  cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE2_t, ndim=1] xind = np.zeros(100000,dtype=int)
  cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE2_t, ndim=1] yind = np.zeros(100000,dtype=int)
  if(oper == 'EQ' or oper == 'eq'): #I didn't want to include GT, GE, LT, LE here
    for x in xrange(xmax):
    for y in xrange(ymax):
      if(data[x,y] == val):
        xind[count] = x
        yind[count] = y
        count += 1

 return tuple([xind[0:count],yind[0:count]]),count
```

Output of TEST.py:
`cython_test]$ python TEST.py
0.0139019489288
0.0982608795166`

I've also tried numpy's `argwhere`, which is about as fast as `where`. I'm pretty new to numpy and cython, so if you have any other ideas to really increase performance, I'm all ears!

Comment: As the title says, I want the fastest way to find the indices of a 2D array given a condition (e.g., arr == 2). I have already improved upon the numpy where statement with the cythonization, as I explained above.

Comment: You speak about numpy.where but the numpy.where documentation give as an example : ix = np.in1d(x.ravel(), goodvalues).reshape(x.shape)
 for retrieving indices. Did you try it? Is it better? Or (a == 10).nonzero() ?

Comment: @P.Brunet, I tried that, and it is just a little slower than regular np.where(x==val). I'm not sure why you would use this method unless you are testing multiple values, perhaps.

Comment: The compiled code for `np.nonzero` (which this `where` uses), uses `np.count_nonzero` to allocate the result arrays.  So it ends up looping through the array twice, but the count iteration is quite fast

Comment: `PyArray_Nonzero` in `https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/c0e48cfbbdef9cca954b0c4edd0052e1ec8a30aa/numpy/core/src/multiarray/item_selection.c` is the source code for `np.nonzero`.

Answer (score 3):

Contributions:

- Numpy can be speed up on flattened array for a 4x gain:

  ```
  %timeit np.where(data==10)
  1 loops, best of 3: 105 ms per loop

  %timeit np.unravel_index(np.where(data.ravel()==10),data.shape)
  10 loops, best of 3: 26.0 ms per loop
  ```

I think you can optimize your cython code with that, avoiding computing `k=i*ncol+j` for each cell.

- Numba give a simple alternative :

  ```
  from numba import jit
  dtype=data.dtype
  @jit(nopython=True)
  def numbaeq(flatdata,x,nrow,ncol):
    size=ncol*nrow
    ix=np.empty(size,dtype=dtype)
    jx=np.empty(size,dtype=dtype)
    count=0
    k=0
    while k<size:
      if flatdata[k]==x :
        ix[count]=k//ncol
        jx[count]=k%ncol
        count+=1
      k+=1          
    return ix[:count],jx[:count]

  def whereequal(data,x): return numbaeq(data.ravel(),x,*data.shape)
  ```

which gives :

```
    %timeit whereequal(data,10)
    10 loops, best of 3: 20.2 ms per loop
```

Not great optimisation for numba on such problem, under cython performance.

- `k//ncol` and `k%ncol` can be computed at same time  with a optimized `divmod` operation.
- ultimate steps are assembly language and parallélisation , but it's other sports.